# Loading large csv file in python in list or numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, numpy

I was unable to load a large csv file(about 1.2GBs from  [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/belkin-energy-disaggregation-competition/data) ) into a numpy array or a list but was unable to load it in python. Is there a way out?

Comment: On the page you linked there is something in Numpy that you can use to upload mat files, [here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) Have you tried that, it could work.

Comment: What is the content of this file like, and what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: @hpaulj its a csv file with shape 81011*4096 and all float numbers

Comment: @PrestonHager i wanted to load a csv file and not a matlab file.

Comment: Yes, but I looked at the page you gave and it's in Matlab format.

Comment: That link has both .mat (zipped?) and csv files.  For a start I'd suggest loading part of a csv with `genfromtxt`, specifying a modest number of lines.  Make sure you can load and understand the data before tackling the issue of loading the whole thing.

Comment: @hpaulj yes i tried to used genfromtxt to load full file, is there a way to load part of csv file too using genfromtxt?

Comment: As of version `1.10` `genfromtxt` takes a `max_rows` parameter.

Comment: Does `np.ones((81011,4096),float)` fit in your memory?  Does it 'plot'?

Comment: @hpaulj using `max_rows` if i specify to read first 500 rows then how would next 500 rows?

Comment: @hpaulj no `np.ones((81011,4096),float)` it does not fit in my computer's memory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my logic for your case. It will only read one line at a time and when the next line is being read, the previous one will be garbage collected unless you have stored it as a reference somewhere else.Even you can use context manager in recent Python versions.

```
with open("Large_size_filename") as infile:
    for line in infile:
    do_something_with(line)
```

Hope it helps you in understanding

Comment: I actually want to load the whole file into a numpy array or a python list because i wanted to plot a graph for the whole  data.Is there a way out?